# Is there a phrase for the action of overlooking on purpose something

Tags: expressions, synonyms, translation

In Portuguese we have an expression called "vista grossa" which means to overlook some wrongdoing on purpose.

This is used mostly when something is borderline wrong/illegal or possibly wrong under some rigid laws and the person enforcing the situation pretends to not notice the issue to avoid confrontation with the infractor. Bribing should not be present on such situation.

Comment: Close one's eye's to ...

Comment: Funny, the word is actually *overlook* (which can have either a passive or active connotation), but if you need to drive home the active idea, consider the idiom *turn a blind eye*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider also ***[look the other way](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+the+other+way)***:

> to ignore something wrong or unpleasant *When someone is having a
>   serious problem, friends sometimes try to look the other way.*
>
> Deliberately overlook something, especially something of an illicit nature. For example, *They're not really entitled to a discount but the sales manager decided to look the other way* .

---

Note that neither *look the other way* nor *turn a blind eye* preclude bribery.

Answer (score 2):

The Free Dictionary:

> [*close (shut) one's eyes
> to*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/close+one%27s+eyes+to):
> deliberately ignore, refuse to notice.
>
> [*turn a blind eye (to someone or
> something)*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Turn+a+blind+eye): to
> ignore something and pretend you do not see it.

**Note**: Dan Bron suggested the latter possibility while I was editing my answer.

Comment: Actually this is not the same thing. Dan Bron got the right idea on the comments above: "turn a blind eye"

Comment: The original expression is not about refusing to notice. It is about both parts involved knowing that the person noticed and they both act as they don't know it. Like pretending to not notice

Comment: @JBernardo The two phrases mean pretty much the same thing.