# "Don't rock the boat" attitude

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

When someone tends to hesitate to acknowledge a problem and avoid involving trouble even if needed, is it ok to say in a negative nuance that

> He/She always has a "don't rock the boat" attitude.

I found the below definition at Collins Dictionary and considering that, it seems that not rocking the boat doesn't necessarily have a negative meaning:

> If you say that someone is rocking the boat, you mean that they are upsetting a calm situation and causing trouble.

([www.collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-rock-the-boat)

I'd like to describe a person who usually avoids troubles and never speaks up regarding existing issues such as social issues with a negative implication.
I'd appreciate it if you tell me appropriate phrases to describe such a person.

Comment: Does [Is there a phrase for the action of overlooking something on purpose](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360783/is-there-a-phrase-for-the-action-of-overlooking-on-purpose-something) (...  pretends to not notice the issue to avoid confrontation  ...)  answer the question? // 'He/She always has a don't-rock-the-boat attitude' is perhaps the more usual way to punctuate such a novel stacked premodifier. But it's not necessarily a bad attitude.

Comment: @FF That's not a duplicate. But there is at least one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it does. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You could say she *keeps her head down* (avoids trouble and/or works hard). *Rock the boat* was cool 50 years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Farlex Dictionary of Idioms* has this idiom:

**bury (one's) head in the sand**

> To avoid, or try to avoid, a particular situation by pretending that it does not exist. The phrase refers to the common but mistaken belief that ostriches bury their heads in the sand when frightened, so as to avoid being seen.

*Lou, you can't bury your head in the sand about your health—please, make an appointment with your doctor and get that rash checked out!*

[bury head in the sand](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+head+in+the+sand)

If you're looking for a noun, you could call such a person an **Ostrich**.

Here's how *Collins Dictionary* defines the word:

> a person who refuses to recognize the truth, reality, etc: *a reference to the ostrich's supposed habit of burying its head in the sand*

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to describe a person who usually avoids troubles and never
> speaks up regarding existing issues such as social issues with a
> negative implication.

**Conformist** (n.)

> One who conforms: a person who behaves in accordance with prevailing
> standards or customs and typically dislikes or avoids unconventional
> behavior
>
> *I'm running with the herd and swimming with the tide and being a good little conformist.*—Florence King [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conformist?src=search-dict-hed)

**Conform** (v.)

> 2a: To be obedient or compliant —usually used with to conform to
> another's wishes
>
> *The building doesn't conform to local regulations.*
>
> 2b: To act in accordance with prevailing standards or customs
>
> *The pressure to conform* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conform)

**Conformism** (n.)

> The action, practice, or principle of conforming; belief in
> conforming [OED]

---

> Members of groups tend to **conform**. What is the direction of that **conformity**? When we call people '**conformists**', we think of them as conservative. **Conformists don't rock the boat**. They don't create dissension. They go
> along with group norms and decisions. They don't take risks. [Stewart
> Tubbs et al.; *Human Communication*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/EBOOK_Human_Communication_South_African/5MovEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=conformist%20don%27t%20rock%20the%20boat&pg=PT242&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> Throughout your entire life, those all around you will constant be suggesting—directly and indirectly-that you stive for security. **The
> clichés of conformity, “Don't rock the boat,” “Be popular,” “Be
> a nice guy,” “Play it safe,” “Why take a chance?”** have unfortunately
> gained unwarranted prominence in our society. (2012)
>
> **Conformists** do not vary their approach to any facet of their daily lives. their behavior is characterized by an almost ludicrous and
> unbending rigidity. [Loraine Kelly; *Through Trials to Glory*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Through_Trials_to_Glory/BK0ECwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=conformist%20don%27t%20rock%20the%20boat&pg=PT57&printsec=frontcover)
> (2015)

> **Conformism** then is akin to free riding on the work of dissenters—**dissenters** bear the costs of **speaking up** but
> **conformists** reap the benefits without paying any cost of their own. [Hrishikesh Joshi; *Why It's OK to Speak Your Mind*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Why_It_s_OK_to_Speak_Your_Mind/BAEWEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=conformists%20don%27t%20speak%20up&pg=PT85&printsec=frontcover) (2021)